# Запрос к коллекции по любому полю. Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Есть коллекция:

```
 {
   name: dima,
   lastname: filippov
 },
 {name: ivan,
  lastname: ivanov},
 {name: petrov,
  lastname:  petya}
```

Допустим мне нужно найти документ:

```
  {name: petrov, lastname:  petya}
```

Но я не знаю точно где лежит 'petrov' в name или lastname.

Есть ли в mongoose возможность за один запрос найти документ по значению, которое присвоено неизвестному полю?

Грубо говоря что то  такое:

```
    Collection.findOne({ name: 'petrov' || lastname: 'petrov' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.collection.findOne({ $or: [{name: 'petrov'}, {lastname: 'petrov'}] })`